# Django Foreign Key to JSON

Tags: python, json, django

I am having hardtime on displaying One field with multiple field (foreign key). Please check the example below for the correct format.

**My database table:** Phonebook Object: http://prntscr.com/jps9lc  **and** 
ContactNumber Object: http://prntscr.com/jps9rr

**Correct format for return example:**

```
    {
        "id": 19,
        "name": "Name here",
        "email": "zz@zz.zz",
        "address": "ajot",
        "note": "ajot",
        "contact_number": [
            "454572",
            "27",
            "752752"
        ]
    }
```

**models.py**

```
class PhoneBook(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique= True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='address')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='email')
    note = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='note')

    def __str__(self):  
        return self.name

class ContactNumber(models.Model):  
    contact_name = models.ForeignKey(PhoneBook, related_name="contact_numbers")
    contact_number= models.CharField(max_length=30, unique= True)



    def __str__(self):  
        return self.contact_number
```

**views.py**

```
def phonebook_detail(request):  
    phonebook_id=request.GET['id']
    phonebooklist = PhoneBook.objects.all()   
    data = PhoneBook.objects.get(id=phonebook_id)
    print(data) #result is combined all contact numbers seperated by comma(,)

    number_data = ContactNumber.objects.get(contact_name_id=data)   
    return JsonResponse({"message":"success",
    "id":data.id,
    "name":data.name,
    "address":data.address,
    "email": data.email,
    "note":data.note,
    "contact_number": number_data #It should the correct format of contact_number in the example
    },safe=False)
```

Answer (score 4):

I already got the answer, I used filter.

Here is my new 
views.py

```
def phonebook_detail(request):  
    phonebook_id=request.GET['id']
    phonebooklist = PhoneBook.objects.all()   
    data = PhoneBook.objects.get(id=phonebook_id)
    number_data = ContactNumber.objects.filter(contact_name_id=data.id)
    list_contact = []
    for x in number_data:
      list_contact.append({
        'id' : x.id,
        'contact_number' : x.contact_number
      })

    return JsonResponse({"message":"success",
    "id":data.id,
    "name":data.name,
    "address":data.address,
    "email": data.email,
    "note":data.note,
    'contact_number' : list_contact
    },safe=False)
```